# Can we say that : $ \exists f_{\infty}\in L_{\mathbb{R}}^{1} \text{ such that: } f_n\to f_\infty\text{ a.e and in } L_{\mathbb{R}}^{1} $

Tags: pr.probability, measure-theory

Let $(E,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ be a finite measure space and $\{f_n\}\subset L_{\mathbb{R}}^{1}$ such that:
$$
\sum_{i=2}^{\infty}{\int_{E}{|f_n(t)-f_{n-1}(t)|d\mu(t)}}<+\infty
$$
Can we say that :
$$
\exists f_{\infty}\in L_{\mathbb{R}}^{1} \text{ such that: } f_n\to f_\infty\text{ a.e and in } L_{\mathbb{R}}^{1}
$$

An idea please.

Comment: Why $f_n\to f_\infty$ a.e ?

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that $L^1_{\mathbb R}$ denotes the space of all classes of $\mu$-equivalent functions $f\colon E\to\mathbb R$ with $\|f\|_1=\int_E|f|\,d\mu<\infty$, the answer is yes.

Indeed, we have 
$$\sum_2^\infty\|f_i-f_{i-1}\|_1<\infty.$$
So, for natural $n>m$
$$\|f_n-f_m\|_1\le\sum_{m+1}^n\|f_i-f_{i-1}\|_1\to0$$
as $m\to\infty$. Therefore and because $L^1_{\mathbb R}$ is complete (see e.g. [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_space#Classical_spaces)), for some $f_\infty\in L^1_{\mathbb R}$ we have 
$$\|f_n-f_\infty\|_1\to0$$
as $n\to\infty$.

Moreover, for natural $k$
$$h_k:=\sup_{n\ge k}|f_n-f_\infty|\le\sum_{n\ge k}|f_n-f_{n-1}|,$$
whence 
$$\|h_k\|_1\le\sum_{n\ge k}\|f_n-f_{n-1}\|_1\to0$$
as $k\to\infty$. So, $h_k\to0$ [in measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_in_measure#Properties) $\mu$ as $k\to\infty$ -- that is (cf. e.g. [Two equivalent definitions of almost sure convergence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/265296/two-equivalent-definitions-of-almost-sure-convergence-of-random-variables)), $f_n-f_\infty\to0$ as $n\to\infty$ $\mu$-almost everywhere.

Comment: You could slightly simplify the end of the argument by noticing that $h_k$ are monotone in $k$.

Comment: @RW : Yes, of course.

Comment: If you define $\phi(t)=\sum_n |f_{n}(t)-f_{n-1}(t)|$, $f_0=0$, then $\phi \in L^1$, hence $\phi<\infty$ a.e. and the series above converges absolutely a.e. Then $f_n=\sum_{k=1}^n (f_k-f_{k-1})$ converges a.e. and in $L^1$, since $|f_n| \le \phi$. It is more or less your proof, with some simplification.

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune : Very nicely put!